# Cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface

Tags: python, django, web

I'm implementing an app using django 1.3.1 and python 2.7.

This app uses Facebook login, but I'm getting this message error in return:

```
TypeError at /promo-racao/
cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface
```

Weird thing is that locally it works. This error occurs only on the webserver, but the environment is the same. And it doesn't point to a specific file or code line.

Searching Google for this error does not return anything useful. Here is the traceback I got from Django:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dev.muccacompany.com/promo-racao/?code=<my code - yes, I modified this part>

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'mucca_apps.social',
 'djcelery',
 'mailing',
 'muitter',
 'customer',
 'finance',
 'blogs',
 'web',
 'social',
 'gunicorn',
 'so_desconto',
 'djcelery',
 'partner',
 'tracking']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'tracking.middleware.TrackingMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/views.py" in home
  24.         return participar(request, code)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/views.py" in participar
  33.         fb_profile = get_or_create_fbprofile(request, redirect_url)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/helpers.py" in get_or_create_fbprofile
  16.     token = fb_auth.app_auth(request)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/mucca_apps/social/helpers.py" in app_auth
  52.             response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  126.     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  392.         response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _open
  410.                                   '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  370.             result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/streaminghttp.py" in https_open
  170.             return self.do_open(StreamingHTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in do_open
  1155.             h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  941.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  975.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  937.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  801.             self.send(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/streaminghttp.py" in send
  81.                 self.sock.sendall(value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py" in sendall
  510.                 data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags, timeout=timeleft)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent-0.13.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/gevent/socket.py" in _get_memory
  261.         return memoryview(string)[offset:]

Exception Type: TypeError at /promo-racao/
Exception Value: cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface
```

Comment: A traceback perhaps? Or at least information on what this non-buffer object is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in gevent. It was fixed in 0.13.7. Just upgrade gevent, and you should be fine. See: http://www.gevent.org/changelog.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I upgraded to 0.13.8. It did change the error, but it's not solved yet. Now it's pointing to gevent/socket.py, and accusing a `TypeError: buffer object expected`. Anything else I should upgrade?

Comment: As before, we'll need a traceback for that new error. But, don't do it here. Create a new question specific to that error, and leave this one alone for posterity.