# gevent TypeError buffer object expected

Tags: python, django, web

This issue's story started here: [Cannot make memory view because object does not have the buffer interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567938/cannot-make-memory-view-because-object-does-not-have-the-buffer-interface)

I'm using Django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7. Now the new error says: `TypeError: buffer object expected`, and it points to gevent/socket.py

Is there any bug in some other library? Here's the traceback Django gave me:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dev.muccacompany.com/promo-racao/?code=<my code>

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'mucca_apps.social',
 'djcelery',
 'mailing',
 'muitter',
 'customer',
 'finance',
 'blogs',
 'web',
 'social',
 'gunicorn',
 'so_desconto',
 'djcelery',
 'partner',
 'tracking']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'tracking.middleware.TrackingMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/views.py" in home
  24.         return participar(request, code)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/views.py" in participar
  33.         fb_profile = get_or_create_fbprofile(request, redirect_url)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/app/helpers.py" in get_or_create_fbprofile
  16.     token = fb_auth.app_auth(request)
File "/home/mucca/git/deploy/muccadev/mucca_apps/social/helpers.py" in app_auth
  52.             response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in urlopen
  126.     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in open
  392.         response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _open
  410.                                   '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in _call_chain
  370.             result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/streaminghttp.py" in https_open
  170.             return self.do_open(StreamingHTTPSConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py" in do_open
  1155.             h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in request
  941.         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_request
  975.         self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in endheaders
  937.         self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py" in _send_output
  801.             self.send(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/poster/streaminghttp.py" in send
  81.                 self.sock.sendall(value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py" in sendall
  515.                 data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags, timeout=timeleft)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/socket.py" in _get_memory
  263.             return buffer(string, offset)

Exception Type: TypeError at /promo-racao/
Exception Value: buffer object expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the problem exactly, but I used python requests instead of urllib2 and the problem disappeared.

I consider it solved.